# how can i get user id from status

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, userid

We can usually mention our friend when we write our status message on our wall page.
I want to get mentioned users' numeric id from status message.
so I have had to try to find mentioned person's user_id(numeric) by using FQL but I didn't find any related field on the specification of the status table.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status

How can I get tag information about mentioned someone?
is there something field to get mentioned user's numeric id from status message in another table?

Comment: Is there some specific requirement to use FQL?

Comment: I feel very comfortable to use FQL :D I love it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`stream tag`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream_tag) table to find others tagged in your posts.

For instance, to get everyone you've recently tagged, you could query:

```
SELECT target_id, post_id FROM stream_tag WHERE actor_id=me()
```

Comment: Good! That's exact, what I want to find!! I did test some query combining table status, stream_tag and user. You're awesome. Thank you.